# Ext Js ajax request not working for failure function

Tags: extjs, extjs3, extjs-mvc

here is my function sending ajax request for checking email duplication while getting response from my php file , not falling on failure function it returns only in success function , for this i have checked  `result.responseText` == to "false" and with else condition now in this condition it shows the error popup message too but donot abort the request continuoues its execution and saves the data

```
    function email_check(userType) {
      //alert(userType);
   var extmail=   Ext.Ajax.request({
                  url: '<?= Extjs_renderer::ajaxurl();; ?>ajax/emailcheck',

                  success: function ( result, request ) {
                   if(result.responseText=='false'){
                       //Ext.Ajax.abort(extmail); tried
                       Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', "email already exist");
                      // return false;

                    //Ext.getCmp('email').setValue(''); works

                   }else {
                       return true;
                   }


                    },
                    failure: function(response, options) {

                    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', "email already exist fail");

                    },
                  params: {merc_mem_tab:userType }
                  });

  }
```

here is my ajax.php code

```
      function  emailcheck(){
    $get_email=$this->db->query("select * from customers where email='".$_REQUEST['merc_mem_tab']."'");
    if($get_email->num_rows==0){
        echo "true";
                    return true;
    }else{
        echo "false";
       // echo "{success: true}";
        return false;

    }

}
```

while on my panel handler i am also trying to check the response but could not succeeded

```
                         if('<?= $this->controller->name; ?>'=="customers"){
                        //alert(Ext.getCmp('email'))

                         if(email_check(Ext.getCmp('email').getValue()) == false){

                             return false;
                         }
                     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return from an ajax request, It is asyncron, and this bit of code `if(email_check(Ext.getCmp('email').getValue()) == false)` won't wait for the answer. 
Also the failure is as Imad said, just for http failures not for false responses. your code to check for response false was correct but i suggest you call a saving method on the success function.Like:

```
 function email_check(userType) {
      //alert(userType);
   var extmail=   Ext.Ajax.request({
                  url: '<?= Extjs_renderer::ajaxurl();; ?>ajax/emailcheck',
                  scope: this,
                  success: function ( result, request ) {
                   if(result.responseText=='false'){
                       Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', "email already exist");
                       //do nothing else
                   }else {
                       this.saveData();    
                   }
                    },
                    failure: function(response, options) {
                    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', "Communication failed");
                    },
                  params: {merc_mem_tab:userType }
                  });

  }
```

Comment: well i thinks itsa better suggestion i will try this one by tomorrow thanks for helping dude

Answer (score 0):

The choice of success or failure callback is based on the HTTP response code. So, if you want to reach the failure function, you'll have to do some :

```
function  emailcheck(){
    $get_email=$this->db->query("select * from customers where email='".$_REQUEST['merc_mem_tab']."'");
    if($get_email->num_rows==0){
        echo "true";
        return true;
    }else{
        throw new Exception("Error : Email Already Exists !");
    }
}
```

It should provoke an error 500 (exception unhandled) and ExtJS will identify it as a failure response.

Comment: it work on  failure function but donot stops the execution it continues to saving data i want to stop that

Comment: Weird ... You say that the php code after throwing the Exception is executed ?